# How to put event on ajax .load -ed content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this chunk of code:

```
$("#contantainer").load("some_page.txt");
```

In that `some_page.txt` I have this:

```
        <div class="nav">
            <ul id="nav_ul">
              <li><a class="nav_a" href="#home" id="home">Home</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav_a" href="#page2" id="page2">Page 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I want to have click event on `<a class="nav_a" href="#page2" id="page2">Page 2</a>`  and load different content in `<div id="container"></div>`. Problem is that browser doesn't recognize that click event had happened. How can I achieve my goal? Thanks.

Comment: Have you assigned a click handler for the `a`?

Comment: try this $(document).on('click', '.nav_a', function(){ //Your code });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use event delegation on the container:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.nav_a', fn);
```

And as long as the nav_a is always a child of container it will work. Otherwise pick the nearest parent that contains all of the nav_a. This can be bound on page load or as soon as container exists.

Or you can bind them after they are added to the dom:

```
$("#container").load("some_page.txt", function() {
  $("#container .nav_a").on('click', fn);
});
```

Making sure to select only the .nav_a in the container to avoid double binding any other .nav_a that may be on the page

Comment: Thanks, delegation worked, however binding didn't. Problem solved, cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You need to fire the callback function, which gets fired when the data are loaded

```
$("#container").load("some_page.txt", function() {
  $("#page2").click(function() {
    alert("link clicked");
  });
});
```

You can't bind a click event on a element which hasn't loaded yet, so you have the content first and then bind the click handler to the element. The function passed in .load() as second parameter is a callback function, which runs when all data are loaded.